# CSS3 slanted div with background image, with image behind the whole thing

Tags: css

It's hard to put into words what I am trying to accomplish, so check out this picture for a sample:

[image: Sample background image]

As you can see, I am looking to create a slanted div with a pattern background (easy), but the other part, the part that the slant is half-covering up, also must have a background image. I've thought of a lot of different ideas and tried using background-clip, background-origin, before and after divs and CSS triangles, the works. Is there any way to do this in pure CSS? I like to not have to combine the images into one or do any photoshopping here.

Comment: how about creating the custom background image in Gimp or Photoshop and then placing it into your HTML code?

Comment: what about a container with a background image, then have another image inside it that is slanted the same angle? you can line it up as you wish that way.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use skew transforms. One div for the top part, another one for the bottom one, skew them, and then unskew a `:before` pseudo for each on which you actually apply the backgrounds.

## [*demo*](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/lAedC)

**HTML**:

```
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='s'></div>
  <div class='s'></div>
</div>
```

Relevant **CSS**:

```
.wrap { width: 4em; height: 28em; }
.s {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50%;
  transform: skewY(-30deg);
}
.s:before {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  transform: skewY(30deg);
  content: '';
}
.s:first-child:before {
  margin: 2em /* width*sin(abs(skew_angle)) = 4em*sin(30deg) */ 0 0;
  background: url(image.jpg) 50% 50%;
}
.s:last-child:before {
  margin: -2em /* -width*sin(abs(skew_angle)) */ 0 0;
  /* pattern background */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the z-index property for your layers and position them whereever you need. Be sure to set the position on the divs with the z-index property or you may run into errors